# USPS barcodes in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, barcode

Running Oracle 11g on Solaris.  I am looking for PL/SQL code to encode the data for the USPS barcodes.  The USPS site has it available in C or Java, but nothing in PL/SQL.

Does anybody have code that they would like to share, or know of some package?

Thanks,
JimR

Comment: maybe try a java stored procedure? See more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chfive.htm#BABGEJDI)

Comment: Which [sort of barcodes](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/usps-postal/) you need to encode?

Comment: Typically this would be a font issue, not a language issue. You can grab USPS fonts for a variety of PC-ish platforms [here](https://ribbs.usps.gov/onecodesolution/download.cfm?downloads=FontsNonAFP&selection=3).

Comment: @tbone - Java could work, and in face, the USPS supplies sample Java code.  The difficulty is that it calls an external shared object that is distributed as byte-code (compiled C).

Comment: @ThinkJet - United States Postal Service bar codes.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - the font is the easy part, we already have downloaded that.  The difficulty is the encoding piece, which changes a sender and destination string into a 65-byte characters string of 'A', 'D', 'F' and 'T' that the font can interpret.  BTW, this is not a PC-ish platform, it is a large Sparc.  But the USPS also provides downloads for it.

Comment: if it uses external resources, maybe try using extproc (I haven't done this in a while, but should be fine in 11g).

Comment: [Here](http://ora-exp.blogspot.com/2011/11/external-c-procedures-in-oracle.html) is an example of an external procedure (in C), from setup to completion.  Seems the setup for 11g is a bit easier than before.  It has a pl/sql wrapper for a shared object file

Comment: Perhaps you could use one of the Sparc Solaris or Solaris 64-bit [encoders from USPS](https://ribbs.usps.gov/onecodesolution/download.cfm). Java and C samples are supposed to be included, so perhaps you could work something up in Java to call the encoder from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem is that the USPS downloadable code is Java w/ C bytecode (essentially an opaque blob).  Possible virus vehicle, so you probably don't want closed source ext blobs running on your Oracle server, just my opinion.  If it were pure Java w/ source, we load as a java stored proc.  Or we could translate the Java source to a purely PL/SQL implementation.  I found this site that has the algorithm pretty explained: http://bobcodes.weebly.com/imb.html.  The author of that site has his implementation downloadable as a .JS file (http://bobcodes.weebly.com/uploads/2/9/1/4/2914793/usps-imb.js).  If you're up for a good porting challenge, you could translate his JS code to Java or PL/SQL.  It would probably take a few hours.

Full USPS IMb specification (in case you go to jail and need something to read): https://ribbs.usps.gov/intelligentmail_mailpieces/documents/tech_guides/SPUSPSG.pdf